# CSS свет с затухающим эффектом

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел эту картину в Интернете, и  хотел бы реализовать подобный эффект на моем сайте.
Попытался сделать более темный фон, лампу разместить сверху, а картинку разместить под ней.
Но я хочу, чтобы свет от лампы выглядел так, как будто он  светится на картинке.
Возможно ли это сделать?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [CSS light (fading) effect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42672519/7394871) от участника  [@user3353335](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3353335/user3353335).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/q/42672519/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать несколько псевдоэлементов для создания этого эффекта, включая `linear gradient` и `transforms`:

**Демо [Наведите курсор на изображение, чтобы увидеть этот эффект]**

```css
.light {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.light img {/*Изображение внутри*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.light:before {/*Создает конус света*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;/*расположить над изображением*/
  left: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: translateX(-50%);/*Поместить в центр изображения*/
  z-index: 10;/*Разместить впнреди изображения*/
  border: 2px solid dimgray;/*бордюры добавляют 3D-эффект лампочке*/
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 5px solid #222;
}

.light:after {/*создает луч*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);/*центры, делает как трапеции*/
  transform-origin: top center;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));/*adds fading light*/
  z-index: 5;/*помещается перед изображением, но за лампочкой*/
}

.light:hover:after {/*demo only, add this to .light:after in production*/
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="light">
  <img src="http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2/73/454/73454031_g20436.jpg" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673277/7394871) от участника  [@butler483](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436942/jbutler483).</sub>